# How to perform a left join of list of dates with an existing table of records smartly

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query to get a list of dates between two given dates:

```
SELECT selected_date FROM 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
WHERE selected_date BETWEEN '2016-03-08' AND '2016-03-11';
```

This gives me the following output:

```
+---------------+
| selected_date |
+---------------+
| 2016-03-08    |
| 2016-03-09    |
| 2016-03-10    |
| 2016-03-11    |
+---------------+
```

The following query gives me a list of all employees required to work for a particular date:

```
SELECT employee.id, employee.firstname
FROM Users employee
LEFT JOIN Table1 table1 ON table1.fId = employee.tId
WHERE table1.day = dayofweek('2016-03-10')
```

This yields:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | firstname |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Mat       |
|  2 | Tom       |
+----+-----------+
```

The results are empty if no employee is required to work on the given date.

I have a thrid table which lists the performance of each employee for a particular day:

```
SELECT * FROM performance;

+----+------------+------------+------+
| id | employeeId |    date    | val  |
+----+------------+------------+------+
|  1 |          1 | 2016-03-08 | 100  |
|  2 |          2 | 2016-03-08 | 90   |
|  3 |          1 | 2016-03-09 | 80   |
|  4 |          2 | 2016-03-09 | 100  |
+----+------------+------------+------+
```

I want to join the above three results to yield:

```
+----+------------+-----------+------------+------+
| id | employeeId | firstname |    date    | val  |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+------+
|  1 |          1 | Mat       | 2016-03-08 | 100  |
|  2 |          2 | Tom       | 2016-03-08 | 90   |
|  3 |          1 | Mat       | 2016-03-09 | 80   |
|  4 |          2 | Tom       | 2016-03-09 | 100  |
|  5 |          1 | Mat       | 2016-03-10 | null |
|  6 |          2 | Tom       | 2016-03-10 | null |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+------+
```

Note : On `2016-03-10` `Mat` and `Tom` aren't required to work. Hence, their values should be null in the final result. The `performance` table will not have entries for Mat and Tom for `2016-03-10` in this case.

I am kind of lost on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must `CROSS JOIN` the `Users` table with your Calendar query.

It will give you this result with one of each date for each user:

```
selected_date | firstname
2016-03-08    | Mat
2016-03-09    | Mat
2016-03-10    | Mat
2016-03-11    | Mat
2016-03-08    | Tom
2016-03-09    | Tom
2016-03-10    | Tom
2016-03-11    | Tom
```

This can then be `LEFT JOIN` with the `Performance` table. ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87c5f/4))

#### Query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, cal.selected_date, p.val
FROM Users u
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT selected_date FROM (
        SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date 
        from            
            (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
            (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
            (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
            (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
            (SELECT 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
    ) v
    WHERE selected_date BETWEEN '2016-03-08' AND '2016-03-11'
) cal
LEFT JOIN performance p
    ON u.id = p.employeeId AND cal.selected_date = p.date;
```

#### Output:

```
 id | firstname | selected_date |    val 
  1 |       Mat |    2016-03-08 |    100 
  2 |       Tom |    2016-03-08 |     90 
  1 |       Mat |    2016-03-09 |     80 
  2 |       Tom |    2016-03-09 |    100 
  1 |       Mat |    2016-03-10 | (null) 
  2 |       Tom |    2016-03-10 | (null) 
  1 |       Mat |    2016-03-11 | (null) 
  2 |       Tom |    2016-03-11 | (null)
```

Answer (score -1):

Build a table with a million integers.  Then `JOIN` to that table for things like this.

In MariaDB (10.0.3 or later), it is much simpler:  `JOIN seq_1_to_1234` -- a magical table that has all the ints from 1 to 1234, or whatever range you like.  [Ref page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/) and [Ref](https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/mariadbs-sequence-storage-engine/).

Comment: I agree that it would make the query a lot shorter if the calendar subquery is move and replace by a number or calendar table (i.e. magical). However this was not the issue in the first place.